# How to get aspect ratio of screen resolutions in mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos, aspect-ratio

I am trying to get the aspect ration for screen resolutions below is my code from which i am getting width height and refresh rate

```
-(void)getSupportedDisplays{

    NSArray* theref  =  (__bridge NSArray *)(CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes ( CGMainDisplayID(), nil ));

    NSMutableArray * rezes = [[NSMutableArray  alloc]init];

    for (id aMode  in theref) {
        CGDisplayModeRef  thisMode = (__bridge CGDisplayModeRef)(aMode);
        size_t theWidth = CGDisplayModeGetWidth( thisMode );
        size_t theHeight = CGDisplayModeGetHeight( thisMode );
        double refresh = CGDisplayModeGetRefreshRate(thisMode);
        NSString *theRez = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zux%zu %d Hz",theWidth,theHeight,(int)refresh];

        if (![rezes containsObject:theRez]) {
            [rezes addObject:theRez];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@" display deatails = %@", rezes);


}
```

I want  aspect ratio for each resolution something like this

[image: like this]

Any Suggestions ?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get aspect ratio from width and height  all you need is to find Greatest common factor for Width and height.

```
static int gcd (int a, int b) {
    return (b == 0) ? a : gcd (b, a%b);
}
```

this will return Greatest common factor

```
  int commanDivideFactor = gcd(theWidth, theHeight);

  NSLog(@"%d : %d", theWidth/commanDivideFactor, theHeight/commanDivideFactor);
```